# Stacks - Evaluating Postfix Expressions in C

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation

My task was to implement int isOperator(char *);
Operands get Pushed, and Operators get Top, Popped and the expressions gets Pushed.

```
  Example:
  6 5 2 3.14 + 8 * + 3 + *
  Pushing: 6.000000  
  Pushing: 5.000000
  Pushing: 2.000000
  Pushing: 3.140000
  Pushing: 2.000000+3.140000=5.140000
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation? 
Here is my intOperator(char*).

```
int isOperator(char *s){

int i;
char Ops[] = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (s == Ops[i])
        return (1);
    return (0);
}
}
```

Here is my implementation for pushing and popping operands and operators.

```
    S = CreateStack();
n = sizeof(postfixExpression) / sizeof(postfixExpression[0]); // Compute array size
for (i = 0; i<n; i++){ // Print elements of postfix expressions
    printf("%s ", postfixExpression[i]);
}
printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i<n; i++){

    if (isalnum(postfixExpression[i])){
        Push(atof(postfixExpression[i]), S);
        printf("Pushing: %d", atof(postfixExpression[i]));
    }
    else if (isOperator(postfixExpression[i]))
    {
        rightOperand = Top(S);
        Pop(Top(S));
        leftOperand = Top(S);
        Pop(Top(S));

        switch (isOperator(postfixExpression[i])){
        case '+':
            Push(leftOperand + rightOperand, S);
            printf("Pushing: %d+%d=%d", leftOperand, rightOperand, leftOperand + rightOperand);
            break;
        case '-':
            Push(leftOperand - rightOperand, S);
            printf("Pushing: %d-%d=%d", leftOperand, rightOperand, leftOperand - rightOperand);
            break;
        case '*':
            Push(leftOperand * rightOperand, S);
            printf("Pushing: %d*%d=%d", leftOperand, rightOperand, leftOperand * rightOperand);
            break;
        case '/':
            Push(leftOperand / rightOperand, S);
            printf("Pushing: %d/%d=%d", leftOperand, rightOperand, leftOperand / rightOperand);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
    else
        break;
}

printf("%s\n", S);
DisposeStack(S);
return 0;
```

Comment: That `isOperator` function should give you compiler warnings. Read them. Check the code at the line(s) the warnings are about. Try to understand why you get the warning.

Comment: Also, try to follow along the code in the loop in the function, what does it do? Does it check all possible operators?

Comment: `if (s == Ops[i])` --> `if (*s == Ops[i])`, `if (isalnum(postfixExpression[i])){` --> `if (isdigit(*postfixExpression[i])){`

Comment: `switch (isOperator(postfixExpression[i])){` --> `switch (*postfixExpression[i]){` : `isOperator(postfixExpression[i]) return 1 or 0`

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler implementation is this:

```
int isOperator(char *s)
{
    return strchr("+-*/", s[0]) && s[1] == '\0';
}
```

That returns 1 (true) if the first character in `s` is an operator and the second is the null terminator (meaning no other content following the operator character, for strict checking).

As for the stack logic, you should make sure the stack is not empty when you pop.